# Proving denseness in $C(K,X)$ using partition of unity (inequality)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Basically I'm trying to prove the following:

> Suppose $K$ is a compact Hausdorff infinite space and $X$  infinite dimensional Banach space. Then the closed span of the set  $A=\left\{ f\left(\cdot\right)x:f\in C(K),x\in X\right\} $ is dense in $C(K,X)$

(for further info $f\left(\cdot\right) \in C(K,X)$ is just the evaluation of $f$ in $k$, where $k\in K$.

Here  $ C(K,X),$ [$C(K)$] denote  the corresponding Banach spaces consisting of all the continuous functions from $K$ to $X$ [$K$ to the scalar field] respectively.

> What I have tried so far is let $f\in C(K,X)$ and $\varepsilon >0$, consider the set 
>   $$
> V_{t}=f^{-1}\left(B\left(f(t\right),\varepsilon\right)=\left\{ s\in K:\left\Vert f(t)-f(s)\right\Vert <\varepsilon\right\} 
> .$$
>   We can see that $\left\{ V_{t}:t\in K\right\} $ is an open cover of $K$ and since is compact there exist $t_{1},\cdots,t_{n}\in K$ such that $K=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}V_{t_{i}}$. Then by the partition of unity (proposition in Folland's book, for example) there exist $h_{1},\cdots,h_{m}\in C(K,[0,1])$  such that 
>   $$
> h_{1}(t)=0\quad\text{for all }t\in K\setminus V_{t_{1}}\quad\text{and }\quad\sum_{j=1}^{m}h_{j}(t)=1.
> $$

If we consider $g=\sum_{j=1}^{m}h_{j}(t)f(t_{j})$ then we can  prove that $\left\Vert f-g\right\Vert <\varepsilon$ and that finished the proof.  However I'm not quite sure about it. This is my tried so far.

> Let $t\in K$ then there exist $t_j$ such that  $ t\in V_{t_j}$ so that

\begin{align*}
\left\Vert f(t)-\sum_{j=1}^{m}h_{j}(t)f(t_{j})\right\Vert =\left\Vert \sum_{j=1}^{m}h_{j}(t)f(t)-h_{j}(t)f(t_{j})\right\Vert
&=\left\Vert \sum_{j=1}^{m} h_{j}(t)\left (  f(t)-f(t_{j})\right )\right\Vert 
\\<&\varepsilon
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, but your final inequality
$$\biggl\lVert \sum_{j = 1}^m h_j(t)\bigl(f(t) - f(t_j)\bigr)\biggr\rVert < \varepsilon$$
is a bit lacking in justification.

We can fully justify this by using the triangle inequality, yielding
$$\biggl\lVert \sum_{j = 1}^m h_j(t)\bigl(f(t) - f(t_j)\bigr)\biggr\rVert \leqslant \sum_{j = 1}^m h_j(t)\lVert f(t) - f(t_j)\rVert$$
and noting that
$$\lVert f(t) - f(t_j)\rVert < \varepsilon$$
if $t \in V_{t_j}$, and
$$h_j(t)\lVert f(t) - f(t_j)\rVert = 0 \leqslant h_j(t)\varepsilon$$
if $t \notin V_{t_j}$ (because then $h_j(t) = 0$).

Since there is at least one $j$ with $h_j(t) > 0$, and consequently $t \in V_{t_j}$, we have
$$\sum_{j = 1}^m h_j(t)\lVert f(t) - f(t_j)\rVert < \sum_{j = 1}^m h_j(t)\varepsilon = \varepsilon\,.$$
(Each term on the left is $\leqslant$ the corresponding term on the right, and for at least one $j$ the inequality is strict.)